# How to get machine client information from web application?

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, hardware, laravel

I am writing a ticket system in PHP(with Laravel) for about 350 users and around 200 machines. I know that already are good solid solutions available, but I'm doing some very useful projects to learn, projects that I can implement in my company, with a good number of users to test it.

So, I want to know if it is possible to get some machine client information, like the machine name, IP address and the user logged in (90% windows 7 machines, but there are a few windows XP, believe in or not) just with PHP functions. Or should I get it with Javascript/Other languages?

I'm not looking for the working solution, just some directions.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language.  Is it your intention to write a client in PHP, or to use a web browser?

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a legitimate bunny trail: http://stackoverflow.com/q/102605

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Sorry, it won't happen again

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the IP address of the remote client, then you can use `gethostbyaddr()` to try and conver that IP into a hostname - but not all IPs have a reverse mapping configured.

In an Active Directory domain, if your clients are running Internet Explorer and your web server/filesystem permissions are configured properly, IE will silently submit their domain credentials to your server and `AUTH_USER` will be `MYDOMAIN\user.name` without the users having to explicitly log in to your web app.

Comment: Don't require your users to IE. Just. Don't.